# SQL Server 2008: How to load/parse a SQL script from within TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Been working with SQL Server since it was Sybase (early 90s for the greenies) and I'm a bit stumped on this one.

In Oracle and DB2, you can pass a SQL batch or script to a stored procedure to test if it can be parsed, then execute conditional logic based on the result, like this pseudocode example:

```
if (TrySQLParse(LoadSQLFile(filename)) == 1
   { execute logic if parse succeeds }
else
   { execute logic if parse fails }
```

I'm looking for a system proc or similar function in SQL Server 2008 -- not SHOWPLAN or the like -- to parse a large set of scripts from within a TSQL procedure, then conditionally control exception handling and script execution based on the results. But, I can't seem to find a similar straightforward gizmo in TSQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: I honestly can't say I've ever needed to do that. Under what curcumstances would conditional logic be dependent on whether a script can be parsed?  parseable != runnable

Answer (score 1):

The general hacky way to do this in any technology that does a full parse/compile before execution is to prepend the code in question with something that causes execution to stop. For example, to check if a vbscript passes syntax checking without actually running it, I prepend:

```
Wscript.exit(1)
```

This way I see a syntax error if there are any, or if there are none then the first action is to exit the script and ignore the rest of the code.

I think the analog in the sql world is to raise a high severity error. If you use severity 20+ it kills the connection, so if there are multiple batches in the script they are all skipped. I can't confirm that there is 100.00000% no way some kind of sql injection could make it past this prepended error, but I can't see any way that there could be. An example is to stick this at the front of the code block in question:

```
raiserror ('syntax checking, disregard error', 20, 1) with log
```

So this errors out from syntax error:

```
raiserror ('syntax checking, disregard error', 20, 1) with log
create table t1()
go
create table t2()
go
```

While this errors out from the runtime error (and t1/t2 are not created)

```
raiserror ('syntax checking, disregard error', 20, 1) with log
create table t1(i int)
go
create table t2( i int)
go
```

And to round out your options, you could reference the assembly C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlParser.dll in a clr utility (outside of  the db) and do like:

```
SqlScript script = Parser.Parse(@"create proc sp1 as select 'abc' as abc1");
```

Comment: Yep, think I'm gonna write a CLR function to do this. Thx Hainstech

Answer (score 0):

You could call an exec(), passing in the script as a string and wrap it in a Try/Catch

Comment: together with 'SET FMTONLY' possibly?

Comment: eeehhh, like the CLR option better, EXEC opens the possibility that it may execute which I don't want

Comment: or nested try/catch in script fails or behaves unexpectedly as a result; naah, don't like it

Comment: EXEC with SET FMTONLY won't execute it - have a look in BOL

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a mechanism in SQL Server to do this.  You might be able to do it with a CLR component and SMO, but it seems like a lot of work for questionable gain.

How about wrapping the script in a try/catch block, and executing the "if fails" code in the catch block?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially very dangerous. Google up "SQL injection" and see for yourslef.

Comment: Not in production code, entirely used by an ops/admin script I and sysdba's control and have access to. Non-issue.